# Rest Web Service with Hibernate Java - Not Found

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jersey

I got not found page everytime in my Java code.
My web.xml code as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And my application config file code is as below :

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("/restapi")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

 @Override
 public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources) ;
    return resources;
 }

 private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(ws.TodolistRestful.class) ;
 }
}
```

And If i'll try with `http://localhost:8080/Rest/restapi/todolist/findallxml` then it'll return not found everytime.

Here todolist and findallxml are as below code :

```
@Path("/todolist")
public class TodolistRestful {

 @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "todolist")
 private TodolistModel tm = new TodolistModel();

 @GET
 @Path("/findallxml")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public List<Todolist> findAll_XML () {
    return this.tm.findAll() ;
 }
}
```

My Todolist class code as below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "todolist", catalog = "angular_java")
@XmlRootElement(name = "todolist")
public class Todolist implements java.io.Serializable {
private Integer id;
private String taskName;
private char taskDone;
private Date taskCreated;
private boolean taskDeleted;
private Date taskUpdated;
public Todolist() {}
public Todolist(String taskName, char taskDone, Date taskCreated, boolean taskDeleted, Date taskUpdated) {
this.taskName = taskName;
this.taskDone = taskDone;
this.taskCreated = taskCreated;
this.taskDeleted = taskDeleted;
this.taskUpdated = taskUpdated;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
 return this.id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
 this.id = id;
}
...
}
```

This is an Todolist class which is generated automatically by Hibernate.

Comment: Is this your server path : `http://localhost:8080/Rest/` ?

Comment: Yes, here "Rest" is my project name.

Comment: Are you using tomcat?

Comment: Yes, it's tomcat v8.0,

Comment: Can you share the Todolist class ?

Comment: Please show your dependencies

Comment: @ShivV, Please check "Todolist" in question.
I have update the question.

Comment: @peeskillet, I haven't used Maven.

Comment: Well show your jars

Comment: Please have a look at : http://imgur.com/vAd1CBw,
This images contains the jars.

Comment: Hi @ShivV,

Have you find "Todolist" class in my question?

Comment: You don't have nearly enough jars. Download the [RI Bundle](https://jersey.java.net/download.html), and add _all_ the jars that come in that zip

Comment: See this image : http://imgur.com/x6JH3BG

I have added api and lib folders jar now need to add ext folder jars?

Comment: Hi @peeskillet,
I have uploaded all jars but got error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/internal/RuntimeExecutorsBinder"

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeExecutorsBinder

Comment: Make sure you removed any previous (matching) jars you had, that may conflict (version-wise)

Comment: I highly recommend learning Maven, if you don't already know it, and use it. With Maven we don't have to deal with headaches like this